# jquery Clone and with remove button of newly cloned item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, git, jquery-ui

I have the following scenario:

[image]

The requirements are when user clicked on + for more Artists it will clone the dropdown list
and new cloned item will have a Remove link as well. and + for more Artists will be move down with new cloned dropdown.
There will be unlimited time clone option.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you show us what have you tried..?

Comment: If you have a question about your code, **post your code**. If you don't, then the question is most likely off topic. What even is your question? I don't see any.

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu and Felix.http://cubeplus.mani-solutions.de/artist/alfred-heinrichs/ here is link see right side and click on form more Artists link. Target is when someone clicked on this link the dropdown option list will be cloned but and a new link will be appeared "Remove" with each cloned item.

Comment: ID of option list will be change every time. :)